# No matching function for call to 'mmul'

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix-multiplication, accelerate-framework

I am trying to multiply two matrices using the vDSP_mmul function, but I get an error "No matching function for call to 'mmul'".

import done as:

```
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
```

Function call:

```
vDSP_mmul(colorArray, 1, rgbArray, 1, concatArray, 1, 4, 4, 4);
```

colorArray , rgbArray are the two matrices and concatArray is the result Matrice.

Comment: Did you right-click and show the declaration of `vDSP_mmul`?

Comment: Did you get the arguments right? IIRC, that error message usually means it cannot resolve the overload, i.e. wrong type or number of arguments.

Comment: Your snippet compiles for me; can you include more context (including the declarations of the matrices) and the full compile command that fails?  If you're working only with 4x4 matrices, you may find it easier to use the matrix types and operations defined in `<simd/simd.h>`, and you'll also get better performance.

Answer (score 1):

[vDSP_mmul](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_mmul) only has 8 parameters and you are using 9 parameters, so the compiler can't find the function you're using. You might want to drop the last '4':

```
vDSP_mmul(colorArray, 1, rgbArray, 1, concatArray, 1, 4, 4);
```

Comment: The documentation you linked to is incorrect. `vDSP_mmul` takes 9 parameters.

Comment: We can use Array in this manner for right usage vDSP_mmul(&colorArray[0][0], 1, &rgbArray[0][0], 1, concatArray, 1, 4, 4,4);